# Canvas toDataURL not working for large images?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a basic HTML Canvas, and I'm drawing some images into it. Then I want to save the canvas as a PNG file. I found the answer here on stackoverflow: toDataURL() sends the canvas data to an image file. But for me, this only works if the canvas is very small (for example, 400x300 pixels).
If the canvas is 1200x900 pixels, toDataURL() returns an empty PNG file of 0 bytes. I have tested on localhost and on my webserver. The image is from the same domain as the html page.

The code:

```
var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
window.location.href = data;
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I have tested in Firefox and Chrome on OS X. A large canvas results in chrome saying "Oops! something went wrong!"

Comment: Does this happen with jpeg too? (f.ex. `toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.7)`) The size you mention (1200x900) should not be any problem. I've seen a lot of problems with canvas on OS X lately so it could be a problem with the graphic sub-system on OS X.. also check the dev. console if it prompt any errors.